# SSRS adding a percentage column based on a specifc column category in a matrix/tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0, report-builder2.0

I have a matrix/tablix set up so there are 4 row groups going down the left-hand side and a column group called RegCompCategory:

[image]

When the report is run, the RegCompCategory column group produces 3 distinct columns based on the categories in the underlying data:

[image]

What I'd like to do is add another column before the RegCompCategory column group that will display a percentage of the "fully-marked" column against the "total" column:

[image]

I'm guessing I will need to write an expression for the fields highlighted above, but I'm not sure how to reference the RegCompCategory to identify specifically the "Fully-Marked" category of data.

Could someone give me a few pointers? Many thanks.

Comment: try to use =>ReportItems!Textbox1.Value to do calculation ?

Comment: Can explain this a bit more as I'm not sure what `=>` is comparing 'ReportItems!Textbox1.Value` to. I'm also not sure where you're saying `Textbox1` is in my matrix?

Comment: Erm.. you select the target and press F4, will see the control ID.
Cast your ReportItems![YourControlID].value to INT/Decimal/Float then you will able to do calculation.

Comment: F4 doesn't seem to do anything in Report Builder..

Comment: @MattHall, Are College, Department, Strand, RegisterInfo row groups?

Comment: @alejandrozuleta correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=Count(IIF(Fields!RegCompCategory.Value="Fully-Market",Fields!RegCompCategory.Value,Nothing))
/
Count(Fields!RegCompCategory.Value)
```

It will count the number of Fully-Market rows and divide by the total rows. I think that is what you are expecting.

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I came to the same answer earlier and it works... just quite slow on my dataset unfortunately (takes about 4 mins to render the report). I wonder if there's a way to do the calculation on the results of the other columns rather than essentially recalculating both columns for the percentage?

Comment: I think that is not possible bacause the column is generated dynamically for the column group there is no way to reference it. In the given scenario I'd create another dataset that calculates the required output at T-SQL level.